# Is there any way to invoke function after all input values came? (Node-red)

Tags: node-red

Hi I have a node like this:

```
function socketIoEmit(n) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this, n);
    const node = this;
    this.instance = RED.nodes.getNode(n.instance).instance;
    const optionsList = [];
    node.on("input", (msg) => {
      optionsList.push(msg);
    });
    // I want to output this optionsList
  }
```

Is there any way to output this optionsList at once after all inputs have came. Maybe something like node.on("afterAllInputs") or node.on("end")?

[image]

In here inputs are OPC UA Items. I want to store their nodeId value to the database such as {PLC1: {options: ['ns=3;x','ns=3;y']}. In OPC UA Clientv2 node, I have this type of object. Problem is, there is no certain number of OPC UA Item node, so there can be 1,2 may be 100 of them connected to OPC UA Clientv2. Because of that I do not know when to send this options data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

What does 'all inputs' mean here?

Node-RED has no knowledge over how many messages you are expecting the node to receive. Each message is an individual event.

Only your node knows what it is expecting to receive, so it would have to make that decision itself. For example, based on a simple count of expected messages:

```
node.on("input", (msg) => {
   optionsList.push(msg);
   if (optionsList.length === NumberOfMessagesIExpect) {
      node.send({ payload: optionsList })
      optionsList = []
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited the question to be more specific. What if I do not know NumberOfMessagesIExpect?

Comment: Then you have know way of knowing and no way to wait. In the example you've shown there is nothing to stop 3 messages arriving via the top path for every one via the bottom path, even if the node was aware of what wires were attached it still could not know how many incoming messages to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you about it. You will get some idea from this flow.

```
[
{
    "id": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "플로우 2",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "f96140956dfb0558",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "{\"test1\":1}",
    "payloadType": "json",
    "x": 240,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "01eb0eaf3200e370"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "d2681609904c2fc4",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "{\"test2\":2}",
    "payloadType": "json",
    "x": 240,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
        [
            "55e5808ddc10f456"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "e8af3ed891507cf7",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "check if 2 elements arrived",
    "func": "var a = global.get(\"element1\");\nvar b = global.get(\"element2\");\n\nif(a!=null && b!=null){\n    msg.payload=\"2 values arrived!\";\n}\nelse{\n    msg.payload=\"you need more values.\"\n}\n\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 640,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "14eefdb3aac678d7"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "14eefdb3aac678d7",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "debug 26",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 840,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "161f9082e8324bb3",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "test1",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 230,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": [
        [
            "7a8df88ed3fb5995"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "83b37802bc0bce79",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "test2",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 230,
    "y": 440,
    "wires": [
        [
            "444c689a2c31c696"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "7a8df88ed3fb5995",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "function 13",
    "func": "var a = global.get(\"element1\");\nvar b = global.get(\"element2\");\n\nmsg.payload=a;\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 360,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": [
        [
            "5364f81813f5a1ac"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "444c689a2c31c696",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "function 14",
    "func": "var a = global.get(\"element1\");\nvar b = global.get(\"element2\");\n\nmsg.payload=b;\n\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 360,
    "y": 440,
    "wires": [
        [
            "03de2c9237fc8a83"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "5364f81813f5a1ac",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "debug 27",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 520,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "03de2c9237fc8a83",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "debug 28",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 520,
    "y": 440,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "01eb0eaf3200e370",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "set element",
    "func": "global.set(\"element1\",msg.payload.test1);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 410,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "e8af3ed891507cf7"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "55e5808ddc10f456",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "set element",
    "func": "global.set(\"element2\",msg.payload.test2);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 410,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
        [
            "e8af3ed891507cf7"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "870f2c835ff3c4ec",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 240,
    "y": 280,
    "wires": [
        [
            "b476f4860f1eef71"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "b476f4860f1eef71",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "function 15",
    "func": "global.set(\"element1\",null);\nglobal.set(\"element2\",null);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 410,
    "y": 280,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "f2b41ebb0aab31f0",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "Inject instead of your 2 nodes",
    "info": "",
    "x": 280,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "508fe12db9199c0b",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "check individual element",
    "info": "",
    "x": 270,
    "y": 340,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "e5d816e483215868",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "620f9c66bdd8aad7",
    "name": "Reset elements",
    "info": "",
    "x": 240,
    "y": 240,
    "wires": []
}]
```